# converting countif to arrayformula

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=if(isblank($F2),,$F2&countif($F$2:$F2,$F2))
```

I'm trying to convert this formula to be useable with arrayformula.

This is one of the several variations I have tried.

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(F$2:F),,countif(F$2:F,F$2:F)))
```

If I change it to follow the arrayformula rules, then the countif doesn't work correctly, and it ends up counting all of the values instead as it seems the range (the first attribute of the countif) doesn't work properly inside the array formula.

The dataset is being expanded all the time, so an arrayformula is the prefered option to use over extending expanding the formula down each time new data is added.

Comment: excel is on-topic. google-spreadsheets are off-topic. Which is it to be?

Answer (score 0):

@Nicolas,

What I've realized that you are trying Conditional Countif. Since you have not shown the data range & values therefore I've assumed what you are suppose to do.

And, I must say your formula doesn't need to be an Array Formula, also just by using the **Countif** the task can be achieved.

Please check and do correct me, if my solution differs, will help me to provide what you are looking for.

[image]

**My Formula:** =(IF(ISBLANK($A$98:a),,COUNTIF($A$98:$A98,A98)))

**The Countif:** =COUNTIF($A$98:$A98,A98)

**NB:** Change the Data Range as you need & Drag Down the Formula.

Comment: the purpose of the arrayformula is so I can keep adding rows without needing to drag down each time as we are constantly adding rows at a fast rate.

using countif works perfectly your correct, but it needs to be drag filled each time.

Comment: @Nicol, if I use your Formula I gets #Name error and the reason is F$2:F you have used. Then If I modify and use mine
{=IF(ISBLANK($A$98:a),,COUNTIF($A$98:$A98,A98)))},, I got the Count. 
And in both cases this Formula is need to be graded since values are in row. Better you upload your Data Range help me to understand if any difference.